# Correct way to add custom buttons with OpenTok

Tags: reactjs, web, opentok, tokbox

I'm building a video application for the web in React using OpenTok. OpenTok has built in buttons for muting the mic for the publisher and muting the audio for subscribers. In my case I also need buttons to mute the video for both the publisher and the subscriber.

I haven't seen anything about a mute video button in the documentation so I built the functionality myself using subscribeToVideo. The problem is that I want to add a button with this functionality next to the mute audio button, but I haven't found anything about custom buttons in the documentation.

So my question is: What's the best way to add custom buttons to OpenToks bar?

Of course I could append a button to the html and style it in place myself, but it feels ugly and I don't know what the consequences are. I guess this is my back up solution if there isn't any other way.

I will probably need to add other buttons as well in the future so I really hope OpenTok supports custom buttons and that it's just me that haven't found how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

We don't have any documentation on custom buttons, but you do have three options for the video and mute buttons on the [video element.](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/customize-ui/js/#mute_audio_hide)

If you want a custom button, you will have to append that to the HTML and toggle `subscribeToVideo` and `subscribeToAudio` properties like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a react sample that adds a mute video button https://opentok.github.io/opentok-web-samples/React-Basic-Video-Chat/

I would recommend that you just set the buttonDisplayMode to off and then recreate the mute audio button just using subscriber.subscribeToAudio() and publisher.publishAudio(). This way if eg. the opentok UI changes slightly it doesn't matter for you, plus you can make it all look however you want.